# Create simple array of strings from object

Tags: typescript

I have object like this

```
  Names = [ 
            {
                group: 'BII',
                categories: null
            },
            {
                group: 'GVL',
                categories: []
            }
   ];
```

I need to create new array of string that will look like this

```
Groups = ['BII','GVL'];
```

Is there some simple solution in Angular or i need to check all properties in object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

`let Groups = Names.map((a) => a.group)`

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

**[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8vhn6?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

if you do not want distinct, do this:

```
this.Names.map(x => x.group)
```

For distinct,

```
this.distinctresult = Array.from(new Set(this.allResult));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const names = [ {
            group: 'BII',
            categories: null
        },
        {
            group: 'GVL',
            categories: []
        }];

let result = names.map(({group}) => group);
console.log(result);
```

you can use `map`

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = Names.map(({  name }) => name.group)
```